# Security of Angular expressions

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, security, expression

I am going through the [PhoneCat](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) tutorial for AngularJS. Everything is explained really well, so i was following along until i hit [step 6](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_06) in which links are generated dynamically from angular expressions:

```
http://localhost:8000/app/{{phone.imageUrl}}
```

While the tutorial states that `ngSrc` is preventing the browser from making http requests to invalid locations (edit: apparently the tutorial means the browser will only call the link after the expression got evaluated. See the "Experiments" section in the provided link.), i am now wondering of how secure angular-expressions are in general. Since the `phone.imageUrl` is loaded externally, it theoretically could contain malicious content and i would like to understand why this would not matter to my webapp.

Obviously the content of expressions gets escaped in some way, so including the following in your code will just print out some text:

```
<img ng-src="{{""><script>alert('UNSAFE!')</script>"}}">
```

but i would like to know if there are some "rules" that you need to be aware of to keep your webapp secure. Would for instance compiling the above code via

```
var template = "<img ng-src="{{""><script>alert('UNSAFE!')</script>"}}">";
var something = $compile(template);
```

result in executing the script when the DOM is loaded? Are there "things" that you should not do in your webapp when you can't ensure that the angular expressions contain the expected content?

Comment: What exactly does "loaded externally" refer to?

Comment: Your js/html-code contains two parts - one comes from server and one comes from user input.  I do not understand what can be not secure here.

Comment: @Bergi In the tutorial it is loaded from a local .json file (provided through a local webserver). However it could easily be generated content or a response of an unknown webserver which has not been validated yet. Expressions could even evaluate variables which are filled by user input, so i am just wondering if it is actually safe to use them without any validation.

Comment: why u want to download content from unknown server? o_O

Comment: Did you never use an API which you did not write yourself? ;) However this is not the point. My question is: "Expressions can contain anything. Is there a way that 'anything' is dangerous to my webapp, or does the angular framework take care of malicious content already?"

Comment: Yes, you should only load data from trusted sources, and make sure that everything else is properly escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know angular always escapes any data bound to elements unless you tell it not to do so.

Your example on the other hand works differently – maybe you're a little unsure how angular works:

```
var template = "<img ng-src="{{userInput}}">";
var something = $compile(template)({userInput: "\"><script>alert('UNSAFE!')</script>\""});
```

So the template, which you have full control of, get's first compiled and then the expression is bound to it completely escaped (no html allowed).

I'd probably not compile external code (`$compile(userinput)`) without sanitizing it first – but that would mean you may be doing something wrong. If you code the right way, you will use `$compile` only in some edge cases. Otherwise you may stay calm since angular will take care of unsafe input.

If you need to bind html to template, then you can include [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize). Otherwise angular won't let you bind unsafe html, unless you tell the [$sce service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) to trust it.

In conclusion, I would not worry about binding data from untrusted sources to my template.